# Counting Text Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an efficient way to count the number of cells in a column containing text.  The formula:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

gives a result, but that result includes cells containing formulas returning "", which I wish to exclude.

The formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(A:A<>""))
```

give the correct value, but is very slow.

Is there a more efficient formula that does not use SUMPRODUCT ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count text (not numbers) but not "" you can use this formula

`=COUNTIF(A:A,"?*")`